# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to get the user data from my database, but what I get is req.body is undefined, I can't fix the problem and I need help.

Error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

my code:

user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { requireSignin, authMiddleware } = require("../controllers/auth");
const { read } = require("../controllers/user");

router.get("/profile", requireSignin, authMiddleware, read);

module.exports = router;
```

Auth.js

```
exports.authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const authUserId = req.user._id;
  console.log(authUserId);
  User.findById({ _id: authUserId }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "User not found",
      });
    }
    req.profile = user;
    next();
  });
};

exports.requireSignin = expressjwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

Comment: So `req.user` is undefined. We can't predict why.

Comment: How i can approach to solve this problem?

Comment: At least show us where `req.user` is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: @IshtiaqMahmood, you add body parser ?

Can you show the code where you integrated the middlewares

Comment: [_"The decoded JWT payload is now available as `req.auth` rather than `req.user`"_](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#migration-from-v6)

Comment: @Ghanshyam Baviskar Yes, i added bodyparser

Answer (score 1):

With v6 of `express-jwt`, `req.user` was replaced by `req.auth`, as documented in the [migration notes](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#migration-from-v6):

> The decoded JWT payload is now available as `req.auth` rather than `req.user`

Answer (score 0):

You can put an [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator ? In order to avoid “read properties of undefined error”.

```
const authUserId = req.user._id;
```